# How do I get a new reference to an object

Tags: javascript, object, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)
>   [Copying an Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

If I have this

```
var a = {};
a.test1 = 1;
a.test2 = 2;
```

and then I do

```
var b = a;

b.test1 = 5;
```

I don't want that a.test1 also changes. How can I get a new reference or object ?

Comment: http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/04/10/javascript-cloning-objects/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Please not that `b` is a new reference to the object that `a` references. Your question title is the opposite of what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create object yourself and copy all properties of original object to it.